# cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable on returning an Option containing a reference to self

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Here, I have a struct `Bar` that has a reference to `Foo` in it. I recently got an error that matched this pattern and wanted to try and create a reproducible example.

```rs
struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: &'a Foo,
}

struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn borrow_mut(&mut self) {
        unimplemented!()
    }
    
    fn create_option_bar(&self) -> Option<Bar> { 
        unimplemented!() 
    }

    fn create_bar(&mut self) -> Bar {
        let option_bar = self.create_option_bar();
        if option_bar.is_some() {
            return option_bar.unwrap();
        }
        self.borrow_mut();
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

so... this doesn't compile
but, if i do something like this

```rs
fn can_guarantee_option_bar_will_be_some() -> bool {
    unimplemented!()
}

impl Foo {
    // ... same as before

    fn create_bar(&mut self) -> Bar {
        if can_guarantee_option_bar_will_be_some() {
            return self.create_option_bar().unwrap();
        }
        self.borrow_mut();
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

it works fine!
now... what the heck is going on here? Aren't these both doing the same thing?

I want to know

- why is this not possible in the first scenario
- but *is* possible in the second

```rs
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:44:9
   |
37 |     fn create_bar(&mut self) -> Bar {
   |                   - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
41 |         if let Some(bar) = self.create_option_bar() {
   |                            ------------------------ immutable borrow occurs here
42 |             return bar;
   |                    --- returning this value requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'1`
43 |         }
44 |         self.borrow_mut();
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

here is the full error ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code builds with the experimental polonius borrow checker:

```bash
RUSTFLAGS="-Zpolonius" cargo +nightly build
```

It is a known false positive of the current borrow checker. There's a crate to work around this issue, called [`polonius_the_crab`](https://docs.rs/polonius-the-crab/0.3.1/polonius_the_crab/). A lot more information about the problem can be found in there.

Here's how you would fix it using this crate:

```rust
use ::polonius_the_crab::prelude::*;

struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: &'a Foo,
}

struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn borrow_mut(&mut self) {
        unimplemented!()
    }

    fn create_option_bar(&self) -> Option<Bar> {
        unimplemented!()
    }

    fn create_bar(&mut self) -> Bar {
        let mut this = self;

        polonius!(|this| -> Bar<'polonius> {
            let option_bar = this.create_option_bar();
            if option_bar.is_some() {
                polonius_return!(option_bar.unwrap());
            }
        });

        this.borrow_mut();
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Apart of that, there's several ways to solve this:

- there's good advice on the crate's website on how to work around this issue
- enable polonius in your project (requires nightly, though, and is still experimental)
- wait until Rust adopts polonius as its primary borrow checker (might take a while, see [here](https://rust-lang.github.io/polonius/current_status.html))

I'm sorry there isn't a straightforward solution to this.